# Keep Navbar Brand in One position on Window Resize

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, position

I am trying to make my navigation bar stay in the same position even after resizing the window. It continues to move on resize and therefore the Navigation Bar and Nav brand are not aligned the way I want:

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <center>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Final.png"/></a>
                    </center>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>        

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Prices.html">Our Prices</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav, .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

.navbar-nav li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover {
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
}

.navbar-nav {
    color:red;
}


.navbar-brand {
  float: none;
}

.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    height:100%;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.logo img {
    height:80px;
    margin-top: -15px;

}

.logo {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```